# Lisp error, undefined operator X in form

Tags: function, lisp

I am relatively new to lisp. I am working on a function that determines whether or not a word exists in a list.

```
(defun is-word-in-list(x lst)
    (cond ((null lst) NIL)
        ((not (equal (car lst) x))
            (is-word-in-list(x (cdr lst))))
        (t
            t
        )
    )
)
```

I am able to compile this code, but when I try to run this function using 
is-word-in-list "hello" '(hello why)
I am getting an error saying

> Error: Undefined operator `X` in form `(X (CDR LST))`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had too many parentheses in the recursive call. Consider the following:

- `(is-word-in-list (x (cdr lst)))` is equivalent to `isWordInList(x(cdr(lst)))` in JavaScript syntax
- `(is-word-in-list x (cdr lst))` is equivalent to `isWordInList(x, cdr(lst))` in JavaScript syntax

See the difference?